# Brunch error when optimizing bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, brunch

When I run`brunch b -o` to optimize and build my project I get the following error:

> JS minify failed on src/javascript/initialize.js: TypeError: Cannot call method 'active' of undefined

Which I have located is down to something inside bootstrap.js is there anything I can do to get around this issue or even better solve it?

**Edit:**
Updated to latest stable version so now using `brunch b -P` but same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a different version file for bootstrap everything seems to be working now.